# Send data with PHP to HTML without forms

Tags: php, html, post

I am making a website that uses PHP to display bookings according to the search terms. I am giving the ability for the user to change a booking. The website displays a list of all the bookings that fit the search terms, showing 'date', 'room' & 'description', 'period', and 'teacherinitials'. On each row, I have a button that reads 'chage'. I want the user to click on that button and take you to the webpage where they can change a booking. I want the data from the row they clicked on to be sent to that webpage.

I have read that you cannot use forms within a table. What can i do?

```
            //Start table
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr><th>Date</th><th>Period</th><th>Room</th><th>Teacher Initials</th><th></th></tr>";

            // Loop through database
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $date = $row['date'];
                $period = $row['period'];
                $roomID = $row['roomID'];
                $teacherinitials = $row['teacherinitials'];

            $sql2="SELECT room, description FROM Rooms WHERE roomID = '$roomID'";
                    $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql2);              

                    while ($row2 = $res->fetch_assoc()) {               
                            $room = $row2['room'];
                            $description = $row2['description'];
                    }

                // Show entries
                    echo    "<tr>
                        <td>".$date."</td>
                        <td>".$period."</td>
                        <td>".$room." (".$description.")</td>
                        <td>".$teacherinitials."</td>
                        <td> <a id=\"change\" href=\"change.php\">Change</a> </td>
                        </tr>";

            }

            echo "</table>";
            }
```

Comment: Have you even tried that? Where did you read you cannot use form inside tables? Why should the form get inserted into the table, can't you just put the table into the form with different identifying options on each button?

Comment: Please be aware that IDs are unique. You mustn't insert multiple buttons/links with the same ID: `<a id="change" …`

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to send data to a website without using forms is to append that data to a hyperlink.

For example:

```
<a class="btn change" href="change.php?date=2014-01-21&room=123&description=Foo%20Bar&periodStart=2014-01-22&periodEnd=2014-01-28&teacherinitials=KM">Change</a>
```

Make sure to [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) any data appended to those parameters, e.g. `urlencode( $description );`.

On the other hand, it looks like an application design flaw if you need to send some data you already know in your application again via HTTP. Maybe you can trim down the amount of data to be send (for example just append the room number).